# Cake PHP With MSSQL Database

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp-2.0

I need some suggestion regarding Cake PHP With MSSQL Database.

I want to use CakePHP app in Linux/ubuntu/centOS server and remote windows server for MSSQL Database ( I know that we can not use MSSQL in Linux )

so in database.php i can define datasource as Sqlserver and remote server address in host etc.

Here my main query is that after that for CRUD, still i can use same find query or i have to write query using other method? i can use Find/count/list/save/saveMany/updateAll  and Bind-model etc same like when we use MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORMs are built with interoperability in mind. Cake PHP does support SqlServer so you can use all the functions normally.
https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Database.Driver.Sqlserver.html